# Linq to DocumentDB: filter by datetime field

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am using LINQ to DocumentDB and I am currently trying to filter the returned records by a datetime field. My query is as follows:

```
      var mycollection = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Test>(MyCollection.DocumentsLink)
                        .Where(d => d.Time >= DateTime.Now)
                        .AsEnumerable();
```

However, this query always crashes with the message:

```
ExceptionMessage=The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
ExceptionType=System.InvalidOperationException
ExceptionMessage=Constant of type 'System.DateTime' is not supported.
ExceptionType=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryException
```

This error occurs because I am filtering using a datetime field. If I was to filter on any string field, that works perfectly. How can I prevent this error?

Comment: have you read this? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-dates-in-azure-documentdb-4/

Comment: +1 to this writeup. It uses ISO-8601 strings which is my recommendation for storing date-time data in DocumentDB.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` is not a supported time, you must convert the `DateTime` to an int so that you're JSON looks like this (for example):

```
{
    "Time": 1408318702
}
```

You need to use a `JsonConverter` and treat your `DateTime` properties as epoch. This code is borrowed from [this source here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-dates-in-azure-documentdb-4/).

```
public class FooBar
{
     [JsonConverter(typeof(EpochDateTimeConverter))]
     public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}


public class EpochDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, 
                                  object value, 
                                   JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        int seconds;
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
            if (!dt.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
                seconds = dt.ToEpoch();
            else
                seconds = int.MinValue;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Expected date object value.");
        }

        writer.WriteValue(seconds);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, 
                                    Type type, 
                                    object value, 
                                    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) 
            return null;

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Integer)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                 string.Format("Unexpected token parsing date. Expected Integer, got {0}.",
                               reader.TokenType));
        }

        int seconds = (int)reader.Value;
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(seconds);
    }
}
```

And the `.ToEpoch` extension method is defined as:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int ToEpoch(this DateTime date)
    {
        if (date == null) return int.MinValue;
        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        TimeSpan epochTimeSpan = date - epoch;
        return (int)epochTimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use ISO-8601 Strings. I think by default, DateTime objects are serialized that way (although I don't think they are correctly de-serialized), You would then need to put an string range index on the field with -1 precision. The nice thing about this approach is that they are human readable in the database. Some argue that it's less efficient but I've not seen any performance impact in my experiments.

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime object in DocumentDB gets serialized to ISO 8601 string format by default, for example: "2016-08-08T22:10:50.000000Z"

You can use the SQL syntax instead of LINQ in that case since DateTime object is not supported.

Note that either you can pass EnableScanInQuery set to true as FeedOptions in the query or set a Range index on Time field with precision -1.

You can store the Date as Epoch as David mentioned but you don't have to.

Here is what your query would look like:

string currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");

var myQuery = Client.CreateDocumentQuery(MyCollection.DocumentsLink, 
                         "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Time >= '" + currentTime + "'", new FeedOptions { EnableScanInQuery = true })
                        .AsEnumerable();